Adding stroke to photoshop texts using scripts
I am trying to apply stroke to my photoshop text using scripts. But I have failed all the time. Here's what I've come up with:
#target photoshop

var textArray = ["Hello"];
var fontSize = 13;
var fontFamily = "KomikaAxis";
var strokeSize = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
    var currentText = textArray[i];
    
    var textLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.add();
    textLayer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
    textLayer.textItem.contents = currentText;
    
    textLayer.textItem.font = fontFamily;
    textLayer.textItem.size = fontSize;
    
    var textColor = new SolidColor();
    textColor.rgb.red = 255;
    textColor.rgb.green = 255;
    textColor.rgb.blue = 255;
    textLayer.textItem.color = textColor;
    
    textLayer.textItem.position = [541, 1144];
    textLayer.rasterize(RasterizeType.TEXTCONTENTS);
    
    textLayer.layerStyle.stroke.enabled = true;
    textLayer.layerStyle.stroke.size = strokeSize;
    textLayer.layerStyle.stroke.color = new SolidColor();
    textLayer.layerStyle.stroke.color.rgb.hexValue = '000000';
    textLayer.layerStyle.stroke.position = StrokeLocation.CENTER;
    textLayer.layerStyle.stroke.blendMode = BlendMode.NORMAL;
}



I have run the code and it says undefined is not an object at line:
textLayer.layerStyle.stroke.enabled = true;
Why is so? The text is made surely, not the stroke.
What am I making wrong here?

Also remember to ask questions in the place where the experts on that subject hang out, first: did you ask in the Adobe Photoshop forum using the "actions and scripting" tag already? If not: that's the best place to ask.
